# changing text inside <a> tag onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change text inside of the `<a>` tag but it's not working. Can you suggest what is not right?

I'm also using this function for the dropdown and I want to change an existing text with a new text. The function works with dropdown but it does not change the text.

This is a code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    var x = document.getElementById("insights");
    if (x.innerHTML === "INSIGHTS &#9662;") {
        x.innerHTML = "INSIGHTS &#9652;";
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "INSIGHTS &#9662;";
    }
}
```

Comment: check whether ```x``` is what you expected by ```console.log(x)``` it out

Comment: Have you tried using `x.innerText` instead of `x.innerHTML` if the text is all you want to check?

Comment: i tried using `x.innerText` and it worked but &#9662; does not converting to arrows in html and it appears like text not like icon.

Comment: thank you, it worked with symbols

Answer (score 2):

The default action for a click on an `a` element is to go to / open the URL which is written in its `href` attribute. If you want some other action, you have to use `preventDefault()` before anything else to prevent that default action.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault